# Android firestore, get keys and values from a Documentsnapshot List

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

What I'm trying to do is:
I get my data in this way

```
List<DocumentSnapshot> docList = task.getResult().getDocuments();
```

It looks like this:
[image]

each of them has an auto generated ID, then literally, noone knows what, there can be any data. So I wanna put the keys, values, and the auto generated ID, of each document, into a class, like this:

```
public class DemoData {
public String name;
public List<String> keys;
public List<Object> values;

  public DemoData(String name, List<String> keys, List<Object> values) {
      this.name = name;
      this.keys = keys;
      this.values = values;
  }
}
```

Question is, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The task gives you a `List<DocumentSnapshot>`, so you will need to get the data format you want out of [`DocumentSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot).

There is a [`DocumentSnapshot.getData()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot.html#getData()) that looks promising for your needs, since it returns a `Map<String, Object>`. You can then get the keys and values from that map with: [`Map.keySet()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Map.html#keySet()) and [`Map.values`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Map.html#values()), or by looping over [`Map.entrySet()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Map.html#entrySet()).